# MediaCodec getWidth/HeightAlignment Invalid

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm using a `MediaCodec`to encode some video frames to H264. Everything seems ok on most devices, but on some devices my output gets a lot of "diagonal" noise (appears like an offset/alignment issue).

The output resolution of the `MediaCodec` is calculated by using the function [getWidthAlignment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.VideoCapabilities.html#getWidthAlignment()) and`getHeightAlignment`. The documentation states that the values returned by that functions are powers of two that the codec output width and height need to be a multiple of. The function returns 2 for the devices which do not work properly.

So, the device I am testing on (that does not work properly) has a native resolution of 1280x800. If I request that the output of the `MediaCodec` be 1152x720 (keeping the same aspect ratio), everything works. If I have the output of the `MediaCodec` be 1224x720 (keeping the same aspect ratio of the screen if the screen has the nav bar showing, so, not the same AR as the native resolution). Both 1224 and 720 are multiples of the width/height alignments that the `MediaCodec's` `VideoCapabilities` returns. Using 1224x720 causes the "diagonal lines."

So, my question is, what is the best way to get a supported output resolution for a `MediaCodec`? Using `getWidth/HeightAlignment` doesn't seem to behave properly on a lot of lower end devices (perhaps the devices are not implementing those functions correctly?).

Comment: The old rule was "make it a multiple of 16", though that had to be bent a little for 1080p. It's certainly possible there's an implementation-specific bug, though you'd hope there'd be a CTS test to catch it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @fadden. Yeah I was hoping the conformance tests would catch issues like this, but apparently not. I guess I will use the old rule (with an exception for 1080p). Is there a way for me to submit some information to see if there could be a CTS test in the future to catch issues like this.

Seems to mainly happen with inexpensive tablets like this RCA Viking tablet I am testing with.

Comment: You can file a bug on http://b.android.com/. Be sure to specify the device and specific version of Android you're testing with.